# How can I write to a file with the same formatting as print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file-io

### TL;DR

While trying to write a string to a file the following error occurred:

Code

```
logfile.write(cli_args.last_name)
```

Output

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-9: ordinal not in range(128)

But this works:

Code

```
print(cli_args.last_name)
```

Output

> Pérez

Why?

### FULL CONTEXT

I made a script which receives data from a Linux CLI, processes it and finally creates a Zendesk ticket with the provided data. It is kind of a CLI API, since before my script there is a bigger system which has a web interface with forms, where users fill the values of the fields and are then replaced into the CLI script. For example:

```
myscript.py --first_name '_first_name_' --last_name '_last_name_'
```

The script was working with no issues, until yesterday when the web was updated. I think they changed something related to charsets or encoding.

I do some simple logging with F-strings by opening a file and writing some informative messages in case anything fails, so I can go back to check where it happened. Also the CLI attributes are read using the argparse module. Example:

```
logfile.write(f"\tChecking for opened tickets for user '{cli_args.first_name} {cli_args.last_name}'\n")
```

After the website update I am getting an error like this:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
> 8-9: ordinal not in range(128)

Doing some troubleshooting I found it is because some users input names with accent marks like `Carlos Pérez`.

I need the script to work again and also prepare it for inputs like that, so I looked for answers by checking the HTTP headers in the input forms of the web console and found out it uses a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`; my first try was to encode the `str` passed in the CLI argument to `utf-8` and decode it again using the same codec, but didn't succeed.

On my second try, I checked the Python docs [str.encode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20encode#str.encode) and [bytes.decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20encode#bytes.decode). So I tried this:

```
logfile.write(
    "\tChecking for opened tickets for user "
    f"'{cli_args.first_name.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')} "
    f"{cli_args.last_name.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')}'"
)
```

It worked but removed the accent marked letter so `Carlos Pérez` became `Carlos Prez` which is of no use to me in this case, I need the full input.

As a desperate move I tried printing the same F-string I was trying to write to the logfile, which to my surprise it worked. It printed to the console `Carlos Pérez` without any kind of encoding/decoding process.

How does print work? and Why trying to write to the file didn't work? But most importantly How can I write to a file with the same formatting as print?

### Edit 1 @MarkTolonen

Tried the following:

```
logfile = open("/usr/share/pandora_server/util/plugin/plugin_mcm/sandbox/755bug.txt", mode="a", encoding="utf8")
logfile.write(cli_args.body)
logfile.close()
```

Output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/share/pandora_server/util/plugin/plugin_mcm/sandbox/ticket_query_app.py", line 414, in 
> main()
> File "/usr/share/pandora_server/util/plugin/plugin_mcm/sandbox/ticket_query_app.py", line 81, in main
> logfile.write(cli_args.body)
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 8-9: surrogates not allowed

### Edit 2

I managed to get the text that is causing the issue:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    string = (
        "Buenos d\udcc3\udcadas,\r\n\r\n"
        "Mediante  monitoreo autom\udcc3\udca1tico se ha detectado un evento fuera de lo normal:\r\n\r\n"
        "Descripci\udcc3\udcb3n del evento: _snmp_f13_\r\n"
        "Causas sugeridas del evento: _snmp_f14_\r\n"
        "Posible afectaci\udcc3\udcb3n del evento: _snmp_f15_\r\n"
        "Validaciones de bajo impacto: _snmp_f16_\r\n"
        "Fecha y hora del evento: 2021-07-14 17:47:51\r\n\r\n"
        "Saludos."
    )

    # Output: Text with the unicodes translated
    print(string)

    # Output: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 8-9: surrogates not allowed"
    with open(file="test.log", mode="w", encoding="utf8") as logfile:
        logfile.write(string)
```

Comment: How did you create `logfile`?

Comment: Is this running on Windows or Linux?  You can specify that the file should be UTF-8 when you open it.  And you can say `print("string string string", file=logfile)` instead of using write.

Comment: Make a [mcve]..

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica `logfile = open(logfile.log, mode="a")`

Comment: Edit your question with the above information.  Use `encoding='utf8'` option when opening the file to support all Unicode characters.

Comment: Can you execute this command and tell us what's the output: `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'` ?

Comment: @TimRoberts It is running on the same server, so Linux. I just tried but didn't work either I get the same error. `print(f"{cli_args.first_name}", file=logfile)`

Comment: @ChihebNexus `[root@atompruebas sandbox]# python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'
utf-8`

Comment: Just in case it slipped by, @MarkTolonen has the right answer.  Just declare the file as being UTF-8 when you open it.  Problem solved.  stdin/stdout on Linux are opened this way.

Comment: FYI, `import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))` is the way to get the default encoding for `open`, not `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.  They don't necessarily give the same answer.

Comment: Where did you get that string?  The problem is in code not seen if you have that as a result.  It looks like a JSON string created with `ensure_ascii=False`  and didn't use `json.load` to parse it.  You shouldn't be dealing with Unicode surrogates and that will cause problems with encoding with `utf-8`.

Comment: Actually, They aren't even valid surrogates.  Did you use `errors='surrogateescape'` somewhere?  It looks like that error handler was used with an incorrect encoding because the bytes escaped are valid UTF-8.  `string.encode('ascii',errors='surrogateescape').decode('utf8')` gives a valid string that can be written to the log.

Comment: @MarkTolonen The string is given to my script as a CLI parameter. There is a web app called "PandoraFMS" it is a monitoring system similar to Solarwinds Orion (in case you are familiar with it). This PandoraFMS is a webapp where you enter in the fields parameters and then associate a command to it, in this case I wrote this script which receives all the params and then parses them to create a ticket in Zendesk. I mentioned that in the Full Context edit, so you could have as much background as possible, sometimes those details are very useful, that is the reason why I wrote that much.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I am just reading more about surrogates as of today I didn't even know anything about it. BTW I have no control of what is passed to my CLI Python script, I was just able to do some tests and found what was crashing the script, but I need to be prepared to receive that kind of text. Your code snippet works, now I see the special characters, could you please write an answer so I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something upstream is misconfigured.  Your `string` appears to have been produced by a `decode` operation with the wrong encoding, with `errors='surrogateescape'` error handling.  From the data shown, it looks like the decoding operation tried to decode UTF-8-encoded text as ASCII.

`errors='surrogateescape'` is a way for an encoding to handle invalid bytes during a `decode` operation.  The error handler replaces the invalid bytes with partial surrogates in the range U+DC80..U+DCFF when converting to a Unicode string, and the process can be reversed to get the original byte string back by performing an `encode` with `errors='surrogateescape'` and the same encoding.

The partial surrogates in your `string` match the pattern of what a `decode(encoding='ascii', errors='surrogateescape')` call would produce when given data actually encoded in UTF-8 - the surrogates are all in the range `surrogateescape` uses, and the bytes they correspond to form valid UTF-8.  In the code below, I recover the original bytes, then decode them correctly as UTF-8.  Once the Unicode string is valid, it can be written to the log file with `encoding='utf8'`.

```py
string = (
    "Buenos d\udcc3\udcadas,\r\n\r\n"
    "Mediante  monitoreo autom\udcc3\udca1tico se ha detectado un evento fuera de lo normal:\r\n\r\n"
    "Descripci\udcc3\udcb3n del evento: _snmp_f13_\r\n"
    "Causas sugeridas del evento: _snmp_f14_\r\n"
    "Posible afectaci\udcc3\udcb3n del evento: _snmp_f15_\r\n"
    "Validaciones de bajo impacto: _snmp_f16_\r\n"
    "Fecha y hora del evento: 2021-07-14 17:47:51\r\n\r\n"
    "Saludos."
)

fixed = string.encode('ascii',errors='surrogateescape').decode('utf8')
print(fixed)

with open(file="test.log", mode="w", encoding="utf8") as logfile:
    logfile.write(fixed)
```

You can read more about surrogate escapes in [PEP 383](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/).

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, however I don't understand how is it possible for the print function to properly display those characters, or is stdout doing the heavy lifting here?

Comment: `string.encode('ascii',errors='surrogateescape')` doesn't make any sense - it fails on most Unicode input, including perfectly valid Unicode input. For example, it fails on input `'ü'`.

Comment: `surrogateescape` is designed so that `broken_bytes.decode(some_encoding, errors='surrogateescape').encode(some_encoding, errors='surrogateescape') == broken_bytes` even if `broken_bytes` does not actually represent Unicode text encoded with `some_encoding`. It's intended to handle errors when *decoding*, not when *encoding*, and it doesn't make sense to use `surrogateescape` when encoding text that wasn't decoded with `surrogateescape`. The `encode` behavior is only intended to reverse the transformation `surrogateescape` applies on `decode`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The data the OP posted looks like it *was* decoded with `surrogateescape` which is why I encoded with it to reverse the process and decoded with the correct `utf8` codec.  Notice the surrogates are all initial surrogates, which is how that codec represents broken bytes.  It looks like wherever that string came from it was decoded with that error handler.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: The answer would be better with that clarification incorporated, then.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I did say something was misconfigured and I recover the original bytes but feel free to edit it if you feel the need to clarify something.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the `encoding` parameter to `open`.  Observe:

```
Last login: Wed Jul 14 15:05:24 2021 from 50.126.68.34
[timrprobocom@jared-ingersoll ~]$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('x.txt','a')
>>> g = open('y.txt','a',encoding='utf-8')
>>> s = "spades \u2660 spades"
>>> f.write(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2660' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> g.write(s)
15
>>>
[timrprobocom@jared-ingersoll ~]$ hexdump -C y.txt
00000000  73 70 61 64 65 73 20 e2  99 a0 20 73 70 61 64 65  |spades ... spade|
*
00000011
```

Comment: `logfile = open("test.txt", mode="a", encoding="utf8")
logfile.write(cli_args.body)
logfile.close()`

Output: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 8-9: surrogates not allowed`

Comment: @CarlosPérez if you're using Windows you may need to use `'utf-8-sig'` to make sure Windows editors will choose the correct encoding when opening the file.

Comment: @CarlosPérez you'll need to remove those surrogates first.  I'm sure there's a question on SO that will tell you how to do it.